# RxJava scheduler doesn't change thread with sleep

Tags: java, multithreading, rx-java

I'm facing very strange RxJava behaviour I can't understand.

Say I want to parallelize processing of elements. I'm using flatMap for that:

```
public static void log(String msg) {
    String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
    System.out.println(String.format("%s - %s", threadName, msg));
}

public static void sleep(int ms) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(ms);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    Scheduler sA = Schedulers.from(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1));
    Scheduler sB = Schedulers.from(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5));

    Observable.create(s -> {
        while (true) {
            log("start");
            s.onNext(Math.random());
            sleep(10);
        }
    }).subscribeOn(sA)
            .flatMap(r -> Observable.just(r).subscribeOn(sB))
            .doOnNext(r -> log("process"))
            .subscribe((r) -> log("finish"));
}
```

the output is pretty predictable:

```
pool-1-thread-1 - start
pool-2-thread-1 - process
pool-2-thread-1 - finish
pool-1-thread-1 - start
pool-2-thread-2 - process
pool-2-thread-2 - finish
pool-1-thread-1 - start
pool-2-thread-3 - process
pool-2-thread-3 - finish
```

Well ok, but if I add sleep with n > 10 to the map after flatMap parallelization scheduler stops changing threads.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    Scheduler sA = Schedulers.from(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1));
    Scheduler sB = Schedulers.from(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5));

    Observable.create(s -> {
        while (true) {
            log("start");
            s.onNext(Math.random());
            sleep(10);
        }
    }).subscribeOn(sA)
            .flatMap(r -> Observable.just(r).subscribeOn(sB))
            .doOnNext(r -> sleep(15))
            .doOnNext(r -> log("process"))
            .subscribe((r) -> log("finish"));
}
```

What gives the following:

```
pool-1-thread-1 - start
pool-1-thread-1 - start
pool-2-thread-1 - process
pool-2-thread-1 - finish
pool-1-thread-1 - start
pool-1-thread-1 - start
pool-2-thread-1 - process
pool-2-thread-1 - finish
pool-1-thread-1 - start
pool-2-thread-1 - process
```

WHY??? Why all elements are being processed in same thread (pool-2-thread-1) after flatMap?

Answer (score 2):

FlatMap serializes back any parallel tasks to a single thread and you are peeking into this thread. Try this instead

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

Scheduler sA = Schedulers.from(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1));
Scheduler sB = Schedulers.from(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5));

Observable.create(s -> {
    while (!s.isUnsubscribed()) {
        log("start");
        s.onNext(Math.random());
        sleep(10);
    }
}).subscribeOn(sA)
        .flatMap(r -> 
            Observable.just(r)
            .subscribeOn(sB)
            .doOnNext(r -> sleep(15))
            .doOnNext(r -> log("process"))
        )
        .subscribe((r) -> log("finish"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. And why I'm not peeking into this thread without sleep?

Comment: There is a non-deterministic emission race between the sources and some thread may emit the elements of the other threads as well.